# How to add a UIPopOverController dim background in iOS 9. (iPad)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios9, uipopovercontroller

Before iOS 9 apple iPad popOver were shown with a dim background. But In iOS 9 when the popOver is shown, it never dim the background view. I want to dim the background view in iOS 9 as well. Any Solution.

Answer (score 0):

What did you try already and how does your code look?

I would create a full-screen UIView with a translucent background color and alpha 0. Before presenting the popover, set it's alpha to 1. After the popover is dismissed, set it's alpha back to 0 to let it disappear.

See here for creating the view: [How do I make a semi-transparent view layer above a current view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283324/how-do-i-make-a-semi-transparent-view-layer-above-a-current-view)

You can place the view inside of an animation block to animate the change.

To restict usage for > iOS 8, use a verison check like described in this answer:
[How to check iOS version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/how-to-check-ios-version)